# Shell script for string search between particular lines, timestamps

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I have a file with more than 10000 lines. I am trying to search for a string in between particular set of lines, between 2 timestamps.

I am using sed command to achieve this.

sed -n '1,4133p' filename | sed -n '/'2015-08-12'/, /'2015-09-12'/p' filename | grep -i "string"

With the above command I am getting desired result. The above command is considering entire file not the lines I have specified.

Is there is a way to achieve this?.

Please help

Comment: using `filename` for 2 calls to `sed` that are connected by pipes is an invitation to trouble. Just remove the 2nd `filename` in the cmd line. doesn't that help? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
sed -n '1,4133p' filename | sed -n '/'2015-08-12'/, /'2015-09-12'/p' filename |
                                                                     ^^^
```

You want to pipe the output of your first `sed` command into the second.  The way you have this, the output from the first is clobbered and replaced with a re-scan of the file.

Try this:

```
sed -n '1,4133p' filename | sed -n '/'2015-08-12'/, /'2015-09-12'/p' | grep -i "string"
```

Comment: I actually thought the syntax of the second `sed` statement was curious with the multiple single quotes...  could you try `sed -n '1,4133p' filename | sed -n '/2015-08-12/,/2015-09-12/p' | grep -i "string"`

Answer (score 1):

Any time you find yourself chaining together pipes of seds and greps stop and just use 1 awk command instead:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/2015-08-12/{f=1} f&&/string/; /2015-09-12/||(NR==4133){exit}' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for `IGNORECASE`, with other awks you'd just change `/string/` to `tolower($0)~/string/`.